# apple standalone webapps caching

Tags: ios, caching, cache-control, iphone-standalone-web-app

I build a standalone web apps for IOS. i notice there are some caching issue which bothering me a lot. I notice sometime the web apps do not hitting my site, lets says "index.php". I observing this by looking at apache log.

I search around and some state that using version number on js and css file. However this method are not working if webapps don't even hit my index page.

Webapps also having some weird behaviour.For example, i add a "alert" when the page is ready. And i add the page to homescreen in webApps mode. I open the webapps and it shows the "alert". After that i remove the "alert" and open webapps again, and it do not show me "alert". However, when i keep testing by pressing iphone "home" and reopen webapps again, it might be 2-3 time out of 10 show me the alert. I got no idea what is happening.

all of these is testing under no cache environment.

Any help?
Regard
Steven

Answer (score 0):

Add a static page to your site, lets say launcher.html that you'll redirect your iOS clients for bookmarking the webapp (at this point the page should contain some indications about how to bookmark the app). When the application runs in standalone mode, luncher.html should just run a script redirecting it to index.php?ts=[timestamp] with the timestamp changing each time the app is started (current date time is the most obvious candidate). This way it'll invalidate the cache each time it starts. The server doesn't need to handle the extra parameter.

For detecting stand alone mode, the following guide should be helpful
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1950-Detecting-iPhone-s-App-Mode-Full-Screen-Mode-For-Web-Applications.htm

Cheers,

Marius